# What is the *real* package name of Librevault

Tags: uninstall

Just installed Librevault file sharing program from Ubuntu Software and decided that I don't like it.  Want to uninstall it completely.

But `dpkg --list` does not find 'librevault".  Does anyone know the *real* name of this invasive program?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no `dpkg` package name for this.  Because it's not installed as a package via the `dpkg` packaging system or the Ubuntu package repository.
It's installed via `snap`, and `dpkg` is not aware of snaps.

Currently, the only way to install Librevault - a file sharing platform - via Ubuntu Software 'store' is via Snaps.  And the Ubuntu Software application can install snaps as well as typical packages.

You need to remove the Librevault snap with `sudo snap remove librevault`.

If you installed librevault some other way, then however you installed it is going to define how you remove it.

Comment: Thomas, thank you very much for both the extra information and the simple answer to my problem.  The command you quoted worked exactly.  Thanks again!